# WPF Dispatcher and Work Stealing?

Tags: wpf, task-parallel-library, threadpool, work-stealing

I have an application which uses WPF for its GUI but, on command kicks off a very heavy processing load.
I noticed that my GUI was rather sluggish when the engine (heavy processing) was running and when using the 'Application Timeline' tool in VS2015, I noticed that some of my engine code was being run on the UI thread.

The engine is started with the following line which, if i understand the `LongRunning`flag, creates a new thread and runs the given function on that thread.

```
        rootTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(DoWork, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);
```

The `DoWork` method referenced above repeatedly uses `Parallel.For` to queue up hundreds of tasks.

Is it possible that the dispatcher thread is 'helping-out' by running tasks from the TaskScheduler queue? If so, is it possible to prevent this to keep the GUI responsive (allbeit to the detriment of the background tasks)?

Comment: Maybe the number of active threads is too large and taking all the cores from the cpu. You would better create a few worker threads and queue your workitems instead off creating hundreds of threads.

Comment: I certainly expect to be using all the processor cores but I believe that `Parrallel.For` queues tasks on the managed thread pool so these tasks shouldn't appear on the UI thread and should be of lower priority than the dispatcher

Comment: You can check the System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.properties like ManagedThreadId in your worker threads. If all goes through the threadpool it shouldn't be on the main thread, unless things are dispatched back to the ui thread. Also use a profiler like (Concurrency Visualizer) to visualize the threads.But note that a large number of threads will cause your cpu to start switching between threads and your process kind of freezes. This can easily be seen in tools like process explorer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible that the dispatcher thread is 'helping-out' by running tasks from the TaskScheduler queue?

No, as far as I know, that's not possible. If some code that comes from the `Task` really executes on the dispatcher thread, then that means the task had to explicity schedule it there.